# Why doesn't file.py print anything on the console?

Tags: python, class

spam.py:

```
class Spam:
    numInstances = 0
    def count(cls):
        cls.numInstances += 1
    def __init__(self):
        self.count()
    count = classmethod(count)

class Sub(Spam):
    numInstances = 0
    def __init__(self):
        Spam.__init__(self)

class Other(Spam):
    numInstances = 0
```

file.py:

```
from spam_class2 import Spam, Sub, Other

x = Spam()
y1, y2 = Sub(), Sub()
z1, z2, z3 = Other(), Other(), Other()
x.numInstances, y1.numInstances, z1.numInstances
```

Why doesn't file.py print anything on the console?

Comment: This is not matlab or R, you need to use the print() command:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why doesn't file.py print anything on the console?

The reason why it doesn't print anything on the console is that there is no code in there which prints anything.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to print things in python you should use the `print` function